# zmmailbox, поиск каталогов, содержащих пробелы в имени

Tags: bash, zimbra

Обробатываю ящики пользователей и вычищаю старые или не нужные письма.

Если папка или подпапка имеет в имени больше одного слова, вываливается ошибка.

Вот пример, ввожу из консоли

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmmailbox -z -m auser@domen.net s -l 30 "in:Inbox/Два слова" | grep `date -d '-0 day' +%m/%d/%y`
```

Получаю вывод

```
Inbox/до ERROR: mail.NO_SUCH_FOLDER (no such folder path: /Inbox/Два)
```

Если папка имеет одно слово, на пример Inbox/Секретари, то все нормально обработается.

Скриптом если делать, через переменную и ее экранировать и прочие кавычки ставить - тоже самое.

Как быть? или это фича такая зимбры.

p.s. если даже название папки на английском - такая же проблема с пробелами

Частично проблему решает включение в ачало скрипта

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Замена разделителя поля.

p.s.s
Как выявлено после помощи, без этой переменной не работает, то есть она нужна

Comment: пробовали перед пробелом поставить один-два-три обратных слэша `\ `?

Comment: Да, выдает - ERROR: mail.NO_SUCH_FOLDER (no such folder path: /Inbox/Два\\\) (ну и если один, то один слеш, два, то два)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как пишут [здесь](http://community.zimbra.com/collaboration/f/1886/t/1088235), должна помочь конструкция такого вида:

```
$ zmmailbox -z -m USER search 'in:"/A Folder"'
```

---

и информация из [wiki](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Ajcody-User-Management-Topics#Special_Note_If_Your_Search_String_Needs_Spaces):

```
$ zmmailbox -z -m ajcody@`zmhostname` s -t appo in:"\"Large Share's Calendar"\"
```

правда, в их примере второй обратный слэш почему-то стоит перед последней, а не предпоследней кавычкой, что, по-моему, не совсем верно, хотя и допустимо.

---

смысл в том, чтобы в строку, ограниченную одной парой кавычек, вставить другую пару кавычек.

если вы используете переменные для подстановки, то внешние кавычки должны быть двойными. тогда в качестве внутренних тоже можно использовать двойные, ставя перед каждой <kbd>\</kbd>:

```
... "\"$peremennaya\"" ...
```

---

уточнение от автора вопроса:

> у вас "\"$peremennaya\"" - а работает именно "\"$peremennaya"\"

Comment: И так  - in:"\"Large Share's Calendar"\" такая конструкция помогла, тут все просто видимо, "\" - это начало блока с пробелами и "\" конец. А с переменной так нужно писать - in:"\"$p"\" -  в таком слчае все папки начинают нормально обрабатываться. Спасибо. p.s. - как правильно отметить, чтобы другие сразу нашли (если такие найдутся)

Comment: Все ненужно подудалил)

Comment: эту переменную окружения, вероятно, имеет смысл передавать только самой программе поиска: `LFS='...' zmmailbox ...`. а информацию по этому поводу, мне кажется, имеет смысл внести в вопрос.